# Problema ao utilizar spring com rest

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, rest, restful

Estou realizando um curso que baixei da net (Spring com rest e angular) para desenvolver um projeto pessoal, porém estou enfrentando alguns problemas que não consigo resolver e não encontrei solução no "pai dos burros" (Google).

O cenário é o seguinte:

Estou desenvolvendo a parte de back-end inicialmente e realizando os testes via Postman (get, post e put)...

Tenho a classe Pessoa e a classe *Funcionario* que herda de Pessoa. Cada classe possui um *Repository* que herda de *JPARepository* e possuem uma classe de *controller* chamada de *Resource*.

Ao tentar realizar a consulta de pessoa (localhost.../pessoa) é apresentado erro de que os campos que estão em funcionario não existem na tabela pessoa (unknown-column-in-field-list), porém esse campo é da especialização do funcionário.

Eu preciso que cada classe possua uma tabela, visto que irei criar ainda outra classe que herda de Pessoa.

Sei que posso fazer sem herança porém queria aprender em como utilizar herança em um caso desse. O que estou fazendo de errado? Seguem os códigos abaixo:

Classe Pessoa:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pessoa {

@Id
@Column(name="cd_Pessoa")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected long cd_Pessoa;

@NotNull
@Size (min = 3, max = 50)
protected String nm_Pessoa;
...
```

Classe Funcionario:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cd_Pessoa")
@Table(name="funcionario")
public class Funcionario extends Pessoa{

protected double salario;
protected double jornadaTrabalho;
```

PessoaResource:

```
@RestController //meta dados. converte json em objeto
@RequestMapping ("/pessoas")
public class PessoaResource {

@Autowired
private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

@Autowired
private PessoaService pessoaService;

@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
@GetMapping
public List<Pessoa> listar(){
return pessoaRepository.findAll();

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Pessoa> criar(@Valid @RequestBody Pessoa pessoa, HttpServletResponse response) {
Pessoa pessoaSalva = pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);

publisher.publishEvent(new RecursoCriadoEvent(this, response, pessoaSalva.getCd_Pessoa()));
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(pessoaSalva);

}
@GetMapping("/{cd_Pessoa}")
public ResponseEntity<Pessoa> buscarPeloCodigo (@PathVariable Long cd_Pessoa) {
Pessoa pessoa = pessoaRepository.findOne(cd_Pessoa);

return pessoa != null ? ResponseEntity.ok(pessoa) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
}
```

PessoaRepository

```
public interface PessoaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pessoa, Long>{
}
```

Para não ficar muito longo o post, para funcionario tem também as classes de repository e resource apenas mudando o objeto de pessoa para funcionario.
Caso não entenderem algo, só postar que tento explicar melhor.

Comment: Primeiro acho bom vc definir qual o propósito dessa herança. Se quiser ver alguns exemplos, recomendo esse link: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/. Repare nas anotações da SuperClass em cada exemplo

Comment: A ideia é ter uma classe cliente que também herdará de pessoa e já pensando em algumas especialidades do cliente creio que herança seria uma boa para usar. Creio que meu problema está no retorno da método listar... Irei tentar com as anotações link que mandaste, que por sinal é mto bom. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: E também a ideia é ter uma única página de cadastro e só diferenciar por um combo na tela, sem a necessidade de ter um campo tipo pessoa na base de dados.

Comment: Como comentei anteriormente o problema estava justamente no return do findAll que eu estava passando pessoa... Corrigi também uma questão relacionada a banco de dados e está tudo funcionando... Porém eu estou apenas no back-end... minha dúvida agora é: Como farei para distinguir qual repository chamar para salvar, criar, consultar no front-End?

Comment: Opa, que bom que conseguiu resolver. Posta sua solução como resposta pra ajudar a galera. E sobre sua nova dúvida, acho que daria pra abrir outra pergunta

Comment: Para definir qual repository chamar o melhor é ter um recurso para cliente e outro para funcionario. Por exemplo, para cliente, `/clientes`; para funcionario `/funcionarios`.

Comment: Além de criar os endpoints para cada recuso é bom utilizar os protocolos http POST, GET, PUT e DELETE de acordo com cada operação.